# Timestamp in DBase7

Tags: format, timestamp, foxpro, dbf, dbase

I'm trying to read DBase 7 timestamp values from .dbf files. From DBase format specification I got the following:

> 8 bytes - two longs, first for date, second for time.  The date is the number of days since  01/01/4713 BC. Time is hours * 3600000L + minutes * 60000L + Seconds * 1000L

However, I didn't get any correct values via this algorithm. Here are some timestamp values in binary representation and actual datetime values:

```
42 CC E1 EC 41 FB 64 00 | 27/08/2013 19:12:13
42 CC E1 ED AF 0E 60 00 | 28/08/2013 08:29:44
42 CC E1 ED B4 DA C0 00 | 28/08/2013 08:42:24
42 CC E1 ED F6 40 F0 00 | 28/08/2013 11:05:16
42 CC E1 EE AE 21 34 00 | 28/08/2013 17:46:57
42 CC E1 EE B1 FB 88 00 | 28/08/2013 17:55:22
```

Does anybody have experience of reading such timestamp format? Please help me to convert this binary data into appropriate datatime values.

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: This file has been created in UTC+3 timezone

Comment: Are you sure your hex values there are correct? 01/01/4713 BC is Julian day 0. Taking the first example above the days offset from Julian day 0 to 27/08/2013 is 2456531.5 days. However converting either the first or second 4 bytes does not yield that value, even with switching the endian-ness.

Comment: I am also having the same issue.let me know if you have logic to find Timestamp from Dbase7 file.

Answer (score 0):

```php
// 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in units
const UTC_TO_JS = 0x42cc418ba99a00;
// 500 units = 1 second
const SEC_TO_JS = 500;

// 42 CC E1 EC 41 FB 64 00 | 27/08/2013 19:12:13
$hexStr = '42CCE1EC41FB6400';
// get rid of the last byte
$unitsHexStr = substr($hexStr, 0, 14);
// convert hex to decimal
$units = hexdec($unitsHexStr);
// get UTC timestamp
$utcTs = ($units - UTC_TO_JS) / SEC_TO_JS;

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $utcTs);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2013-08-27 19:12:13
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type is DBase VII's timestamp (@) then the value is a big endian double precision floating point where the date part is the calendar days since the start of the current calendar (0001-01-01 has the value of 1) expressed in milliseconds and the time part is the milliseconds since midnight.

```
function TimestampToUnixMilliseconds(milliseconds) {
    var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    millisecondsBetween0001_01_01And1970_01_01 = 719164 * millisecondsPerDay,
    date = Math.trunc(milliseconds / millisecondsBetween0001_01_01And1970_01_01);
    return date
    - millisecondsBetween0001_01_01And1970_01_01
    + millisecondsPerDay
    + Math.round(milliseconds - date);
}
```

Be aware that the DBase VII's integer (I), double (O) and autoincrement (+) types also use big endian. The integer and double use the leftmost byte as a sign bit where 0 means negative. And the FoxPro's binary type (B) is actually DBase VII's double (O) so you have to check for its 8 byte width and parse it like such, instead of searching in the memo.